# Open Coding4Fun User Control from LongListSelector

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

Does anyone know how I can open up a Coding4Fun User Control when I tap on a particular item in my LongListSelector. I want some items to take me to different pages but also for some items to open up a User Control.

```
Partial Public Class Station_Chooser
    Inherits PhoneApplicationPage

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim source As New List(Of AStations)()
        source.Add(New AStations("Aldgate", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Aldgate East", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Angel", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Baker Street", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Bank", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Barbican", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Bayswater", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Blackfriars", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Bond Street", "Fare zone 1"))
        source.Add(New AStations("Borough", "Fare zone 1"))

        Dim DataSource As List(Of AlphaKeyGroup(Of AStations)) = AlphaKeyGroup(Of AStations).CreateGroups(source, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, Function(s As AStations)
                                                                                                                                                                              Return s.Station
                                                                                                                                                                          End Function, True)
        AllStations.ItemsSource = DataSource
    End Sub

    Public Class AStations
        Public Property Station() As String
            Get
                Return m_Station
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_Station = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Station As String

        Public Property FareZone() As String
            Get
                Return m_FareZone
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_FareZone = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_FareZone As String

        Public Property Link() As String
            Get
                Return m_Link
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_Link = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Link As String

        Public Sub New(station As String, farezone As String, link As String)
            Me.Station = station
            Me.FareZone = farezone
            Me.Link = link
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this a "quick fix".  I am assuming AllStations is your LongListSelector.  So find the code for it in XAML.
**OR**

Go to proprities windows, and click on event handlers (it has a lightning icon).  Scroll down to SelectionChanged even, and double click on the textbox.  It will create an event handler in the code. it will look something like this.

```
 private void AllStations_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your logic

        }
    }
```

Now you can handle the event.  So all you have to do when you test on your emulator or device, is to just tap on the item.

Comment: OK. I must however point out that I already had the following code within the page:

Comment: Private Sub BakerlooItem_Tap(sender As Object, e As Input.GestureEventArgs)
            Dim element As FrameworkElement = TryCast(sender, FrameworkElement)
            Dim item As Bakerloo = TryCast(element.DataContext, Bakerloo)

            Dim addressString As String = item.Link
            Dim pageUri As Uri = New Uri(addressString, UriKind.Relative)
            NavigationService.Navigate(pageUri)
        End Sub

Comment: What can I do to this code to also enable Coding4Fun controls to appear?

Comment: anyone know what to do?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, do you mean like a link?

Comment: Do you still need help? @m.findlay93